# How to change featured content to a different tag in Wordpress Twenty Fourteen?

Tags: php, functions, content, featured-post, theme-twenty-fourteen

In twenty fourteen theme, we’d like to know how to change the features content tag. Currently it’s set as `featured`.

Now, we would like to know how to code this for different page templates.

We notice in `page.php` there is a piece of code calling the template part `featured-content`.

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
    // Include the featured content template.
    get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
}
?>
```

From our understanding this calls the file `featured-content.php`. In this file, is there a way to decide the tag. We imagine you can do it using an if statement and the `$tag` or `$term` variable inside an array. But we’re not completely sure.

Our idea is to create three pages on our site, each using a different tag to show different posts in the featured content section.

Can this be done and can anyone provide us with the code or logic to do it?

Thanks in advance!
the LWdesign team

Answer (score 5):

The internal implementation details of that feature are of questionable sanity.

1. If you take a look at said `featured-content.php` template you would see
2. that it get posts from `twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts()` however
3. the only thing that function has is `twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts` filter
4. from quick look at which in peculiar fashion nothing is actually getting hooked
5. because `twentyfourteen_setup()` declares `featured-content` feature
6. with configuration defining `featured_content_filter` as the one above
7. to which `Featured_Content` class hooks its `get_featured_posts()` method
8. which burrows further to `get_featured_posts_ids()` method
9. which calculates, caches, and returns those IDs

So there are a... *few* points at which you can work with... *this*. :)

From practical point of view you would probably want to hook into `twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts` filter and conditionally return different set of posts as you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the tag on default templates, you can also do it in dashboard.  :)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Twenty_Fourteen

[image]