# How do I add a custom post type to the Featured Content in twenty fourteen theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, functions, theme-twenty-fourteen

[This wpmudev post](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-twentyfourteen-theme-a-flawed-beauty/) sums up my feeling exactly about twenty fourteen:

> Featured Content does not support custom post types – only posts are selected even if the custom post type supports the Tags taxonomy

I've added two CPT that share a custom taxonomy.  I've tried tagging them without any luck, looked at `inc/featured-content.php`,`js/slider.js` and `functions.php`.

How can I add these post types so they display in the Featured Content slider on homepage?

[related QA on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136320/how-to-change-featured-content-to-a-different-tag-in-wordpress-twenty-fourteen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts` filter:

It took some digging, to figure out how the `twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts` filter is used in the *TwentyFourteen* theme ;-)

---

The featured content is [fetched](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9-branch/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/featured-content.php#L21) with:

```
$featured_posts = twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts();
```

but this function is only this single line:

```
return apply_filters( 'twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts', array() );
```

so where's the meat?

---

We find it in the [`Featured_Content`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9-branch/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/inc/featured-content.php) class, starting with this [line](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9-branch/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/inc/featured-content.php#L86):

```
add_filter( $filter, array( __CLASS__, 'get_featured_posts' ) );
```

where `$filter` comes from:

```
$filter = $theme_support[0]['featured_content_filter'];
```

where:

```
$theme_support = get_theme_support( 'featured-content' );
```

---

In [`functions.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9-branch/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php#L108) we find:

```
// Add support for featured content.
add_theme_support( 'featured-content', array(
    'featured_content_filter' => 'twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts',
    'max_posts' => 6,
) );
```

so we finally see that:

```
$filter === 'twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts';
```

---

### Example:

To override the default *featured content posts*, you can then try this:

```
add_filter( 'twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts', function( $posts ){

    // Modify this to your needs:
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'       => array( 'cpt1', 'cpt2' ),
        'posts_per_page'  => 6,
        'featured_tax'    => 'featured_term' 
    ) );

    return $posts;

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

The next step would be to connect it to the *theme customizer* and maybe cache it.

Hopefully you can continue the journey from here ;-)

Comment: ps: I just checked out the link provided by the OP, and I can see that the first part of my answer is somewhat redundant, since @Rarst already goes through similar  steps to understand how this filter works. So check out his great answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks for digging around.  Your explanation is excellent.  Btw, didn't know you could direct link to line numbers in github.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes I really like this github feature, makes life much easier ;-)